# Get an idea of the ages of linux machines

Tags: linux, system

I have a number of servers that has been running for a long period of time (on the time scale of years) but I want to know exactly how old they are from the command line because I cannot physically access them. Basically, I have sudo accounts but I cannot physically go to the machine room to read the manufacture labels. How do I get an idea of that from the command line? A rough idea would be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found 2 things which may help you:

links are in french :s (you can use google translate to traduce them)
http://dev.petitchevalroux.net/linux/connaitre-nom-carte-mere-linux.72.html
http://dev.petitchevalroux.net/linux/lshw-recuperer-les-informations-hardware-machine-l.244.html

http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw

in these 2 case you can get an idea, by seeing firmware versions(and some version show a release date) if you dont see date, you can try to find it's release date on the web

`dmidecode` show bios version etc

Comment: The BOIS can be upgraded, so it is not for certain the hardware manufacturing time. The lshw can give me serial number and/or model numbers, but they are indirect information on the hardware age. However, for old systems, this tool may not be available. Anyway, these two give me an idea so I still give you credit. Thanks.